# Wiper inserts for Mazda wagon rear blade

Tags: windshield-wipers, mazda-6

The rear wiper blade on a Mazda 6 wagon is a custom 12" arm, so it can't be replaced using just any 12" wiper replacement.

I remember in the old days we would buy just the rubber insert and not routinely replace the wiper arms, so I bought a "6mm universal insert" but that didn't fit the metal supports on the rear arm either.

What are the different types of replacement inserts, and how can I tell which will fit a particular wiper arm?

Answer (score 1):

You want an integrated wiper arm, something like the below:

[image: Trico factory replacement wiper arm]

You can search for your model online [at Trico](http://www.tricoproducts.com/Drivers/FindYourWiperSize) or at other manufacturer web sites. Trico has a [page that describes the refill types they offer](http://www.tricoproducts.com/Drivers/WiperProducts/MoreProducts/WiperRefills), but I don't see a 12" choice there.

Comment: That's the sort of thing I have been buying, but it still seems silly to throw out the whole arm when the only thing that degrades is the edge of that rubber (or sometimes silicone) piece.

Comment: I agree, and it annoys me that most auto parts stores seemed to stop selling blade refills and only sell whole blades at much higher cost. (I buy refills online instead) But I've never seen refills for those little plastic rear blades. Going to the manufacturer's websites would be the definitive source. I didn't see 12" refills on Trico's page, for example. (12" was the size in the example image)

Comment: Ah ha: So perhaps we've caught on to a manufacturer conspiracy!